# How do I get ipython shell to auto-reload code?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, autoreload

I'm using Python 3.9 with ipython 8.16.1.  I would like my code to autoreload when I enter my shell using

```
python manage.py shell
```

but right now I have to enter the commands

```
> load_ext autoreload
```

and then

```
> autoreload
```

How do I configure the shell to do this auomtaically?  I tried adding this to my shell_startup.py file

```
load_ext autoreload
```

but this results in this error when I start my shell ...

```
    load_ext autoreload
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

ipython config file will be present in '.ipython/profile_default/'. The config file name will be either ipython_config.py or ipython_notebook_config.py or something similar. Search for "c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines" and "c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions". Change the above to the following respectively and uncomment.

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
```

Comment: Within my ~/.ipython file, I only have three directories, "extensions," "nbextensions," and "profile_default".  Unfortunately there i no file matching "*config*" within any of those or their children directories.

Comment: Yes, See inside the profile_default directory. The name of ipython config file is ipython_config.py.

In case if it were not there, you can create as well seeing the instructions in this link:
https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html